# Multiple COUNTIFS ignoring duplicate values in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have seem some example of how to exclude duplicates but I've unfortunately been unable to implement then. I have two tables which I'm using the following COUNTIFS statement for:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[FILTERED_RFC_COVERAGE],"*" &Table2[@RFC]& "*",Table1[REL_NUM],[@[RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER]])
```

This gives me a result that would be inaccurate because there is a good chance that the total is returning duplicates. A little explanation on the data:

**Table1** contains (for simplicity sake) three columns:

```
 Release Number  |  Test ID  |  RFC Number
    53           |  1        |  1212, 1213
    53           |  1        |  1212, 1213
    53           |  2        |  1212
    53           |  3        |  1213
    53           |  4        |  1214, 1215
    53           |  4        |  1214, 1215
```

**Table 2** contains single RFC numbers per row:

```
RFC Number
    1212 
    1213
    1214
    1215
```

Because `RFC Number` is a text field and can contain multiple RFCs, in Excel I'm essentially using a like operator to match an `RFC number` with the RFC numbers column, this is followed by ensuring the uniqueness of release. This currently gives me:

```
RFC Number   |  Tests
    1212     |  3
    1213     |  3
    1214     |  2
    1215     |  2
```

This is of course wrong, the correct representation would be:

```
RFC Number   |  Tests
    1212     |  2
    1213     |  2
    1214     |  1
    1215     |  1
```

This no longer double counts the same ID. I believe FREQUENCY or SUMPRODUCT could be used but if this can be explained a little that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some further assistance around the web I was able to come out with a solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(Range=Cell))*(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&Cell&"*",Range2)))/MMULT(--(Range2=TRANSPOSE(Range2)),--(Range2=Range2)))
```

The first `Range=Cell` combination is my condition on a specific release - this is followed by a search on the RFC Number against a **concatenated column** - the column is a combination of the Release Number, Test ID and RFC Number.

This gives me the correct output however I only use this against a small dataset - I'm not sure how the performance would hold against a larger set.

It's unfortunately a limitation of the data extract / table that I am pulling that has prompted this scenario. There is a MUCH better way to handle this within the tables rather then excel.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a CSE(Ctrl+Shift+Enter) formula which you can use to find unique values from your RFC Numbers. After that operation you can use your formula and you get the same result as you had now.

Assumption:
In my test sheet I have this layout:

Column "A" = Release Number

Column "B" = test ID

Column "C" = RFC number

This is the same layout as you give us on first screen.

Now please create new column "D" = Unique

In D2 cell in formula bar enter this code:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$C$2:$C$7),0)),"")
```

and after that confirmed by ctrl+shift+enter. (if you do it correctly your formula will have {} this type of brackets)

Now you should do autofill, in this case to cell D7

After this operation you can adjust your formula to unique values from you RFC number list.